# scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom: Fails with big arrays

Tags: memory-management, numpy, ram

Given a numpy array of shape (32,32,13,N):

`scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom(X,[0.5,0.5,1,1],order=0)` is ok with `N=40000` and `X.dtype == 'float64'` and fails with `N=50000, x.dtype=='float32'`.

The output error I get is `command terminated` nothing else.

I don't think it's a memory error because of the above example (i.e. 50000*4 < 40000*8) and I am on a 64GB RAM machine (memory size of the bigger array is around 5GB).

Any other possible reason of failure?

*** python version is 2.7.6 64-bit, numpy 1.8.1

Comment: is your Python 64 bit?

Comment: 64-bit, added above as well.